# Wrapping an existing RTP stream with RTSP

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtp

I have a RTP multicast stream from ffmpeg that requires users to use external SDP files, as this sometimes becomes a problem I was thinking of wrapping the stream using RTSP.

I have an application that already makes some management for the RTP stream, so it would be useful to have the RTSP wrapper inside it as well, although I don't want the wrapper to do anything beyond delivering the SDP information. Right now I'd say I'm correctly delivering the SDP information (otherwise it's stuck in that request), however I'm not getting any PLAY command, the player is stuck after the SETUP request, so I guess my reply is wrong, but after testing many different values for the Transport header I haven't been able to get anything beyond this point.

This is the SDP:

`v=0
 o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
 s=No Name
 c=IN IP4 236.0.0.1
 t=0 0
 a=tool:libavformat 56.7.102
 m=video 2000 RTP/AVP 96
 b=AS:500
 a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
 a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1`

This is a sample SETUP request from VLC:

`SETUP rtsp://127.0.0.1:34343/live.sdp/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.1.5 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.05.27)
Transport: RTP/AVP;multicast;client_port=2000-2001`

And one of many replies I've tried:

`RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Transport: RTP/AVP;multicast;client_port=2000-2001;source=236.0.0.1;port=2000-2001
Session: 0456804596`

I've tried using destination instead of source, server_port instead of port, also, although the RTP multicast port is 2000, I've seen the streaming is also using other ports like 57927 and 57928, so I've tried those ones as well, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my two cents, but from the logical point of view a `PLAY` command for a multicast RTSP stream does not make any sense since the clients will get the media as soon as they join the group. The multicast stream as such does not have state.

Is the multicast RTP stream active at this point? Maybe VLC is actually joining the group after the `SETUP` response but no data is being transmitted to it? Also you can use VLC error log to see what is going on.

**EDIT**

Here is an example RTSP session with a multicast stream between VLC and an IP camera:

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.3.142/stream/profile1=m RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 5
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Accept: application/sdp

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 5
Connection: Keep-alive
Date: Sat, 10 Jan 2015 16:54:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 352

v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.3.142
s=rtsp://192.168.3.142/stream/profile1
t=0 0
a=control:*
m=video 2014 RTP/AVP 99
a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
a=fmtp:99 sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LgKdoB4Aiflm4CAgwE,aM48gA==;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e029
a=control:rtsp://192.168.3.142/stream/profile1/AVCESEnc
a=framerate:30.0
c=IN IP4 239.100.10.10/1

SETUP rtsp://192.168.3.142/stream/profile1/AVCESEnc RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 6
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Transport: RTP/AVP;multicast;client_port=2014-2015

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 6
Connection: Keep-alive
Date: Sat, 10 Jan 2015 16:54:28 GMT
Session: 241934337;timeout=60
Transport: RTP/AVP;multicast;destination=239.100.10.10;port=2014-2015;ttl=1

PLAY rtsp://192.168.3.142/stream/profile1=m RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 7
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Session: 241934337
Range: npt=0.000-

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 7
Connection: Keep-alive
Date: Sat, 10 Jan 2015 16:54:28 GMT
Session: 241934337
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://192.168.3.142/stream/profile1/AVCESEnc;seq=14604;rtptime=3766807430

GET_PARAMETER rtsp://192.168.3.142/stream/profile1=m RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 8
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Session: 241934337

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 8
Connection: Keep-alive
Date: Sat, 10 Jan 2015 16:54:29 GMT
Session: 241934337

TEARDOWN rtsp://192.168.3.142/stream/profile1=m RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 9
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
Session: 241934337

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 9
Connection: Close
Date: Sat, 10 Jan 2015 16:54:31 GMT
Session: 241934337
```

**EDIT 2**

As can be seen lower in the comments, Neverbirth pointed out that the issue was not in the `SETUP` command but in the HTTP headers for the `DESCRIBE` command - a wrong content length was used in the response. After fixing that the problem was solved.

Comment: Yes, the RTP stream is active at that point. It would make sense not to send a PLAY command, but according to the RTSP spec the PLAY command should be sent. Also, the VLC log hasn't proven too useful... unless there is another log aside from the log window.

Comment: @Neverbirth To give some more help I tried VLC against an IP camera with multicast to see what happens. VLC does send the play command, so I tried to see what could possibly be wrong with the `SETUP` response. The camera describes the transport as `Transport: RTP/AVP;multicast;destination=239.100.10.10;port=2014-2015;ttl=1`. Looking at the RFC it does not state that `destination` and `ttl` should be mandatory, but still all the examples use them. I'd say try adding `destination` and `ttl` and I don't think you need to set source to the multicast IP since the stream actually comes from your IP.

Comment: As I said in the original post I already tried it, but will again just in case. How did you see the command? Wireshark, some proxy or through some VLC log? could you post the full SETUP reply in bin format? maybe I'm missing some header...

Comment: @Neverbirth yeah sorry, I missed that. I captured the traffic with Wireshark, I can put the whole RTSP session here if that helps.

Comment: It won't hurt to get the complete session. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I found the cause of the error. It was not my SETUP reply, but the one to DESCRIBE, my Content-Length was n - 1, so I guess the client was caching that last character and making my SETUP reply not valid. Thanks for your help, surely I wouldn't have seen the problem without it. If you edit again the reply, and add my comment or something similar I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Neverbirth sure, I edited the answer, glad that the RTSP session example was helpful.